# Insert unique record in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data to payments table where Ref column needs to be unique. In below code,  with `$ref=$_POST['PAYMENT_ID'];` I am inserting always a new ref no with other column value in each post back. Sometimes it is posting duplicate ref no. I am trying to keep the ref no unique.

For this I have written following code.What I am trying to do is if existing Ref Column value doesn't match with new `$ref=$_POST['PAYMENT_ID']` value then it will insert data.But it is not working and inserting ref no yet it is matched with new ref no.

How can I do this?

```
<?php
$ref=$_POST['PAYMENT_ID'];
$pending = "Pending";
$method = "Uploaded funds";
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$time=$_POST['TIMESTAMPGMT'];
$type = "Pm";

$table_payments = $wpdb->prefix . "payments";
$check=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT Ref FROM $table_payments");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

         if ($checkrows!=$ref) {
                if($hash2==$_POST['V2_HASH']){
                    $wpdb->insert( $table_payments, array(
                        'Method' => $method,  
                        'Today' => $today,
                        'Time' => $time,
                        'Ref' => $ref,
                        'Batch' => $batch,                      
                        'Type'  => $type,
                        'Status' => $pending,
                        'User' => $me
          ));}}
      ?>
```

Comment: In table structure you have mention  Payment_id is unique, it is a another way to define it unique

Comment: Payment_id is unique in first post back but when I refresh the page multiple times it always inserting the same record again and again.This creating the problem and for this i need to check the payment_id . so that it won't insert duplicate records with same payment ref

Comment: May be $_POST['PAYMENT_ID']  this is not returning unique id. You can add salt data to make it unique . It can be current time in milliseconds/random number/current data time. Depending on your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `$Ref` is a user's submitted value and `$checkrows` holds the total number of rows in `$table_payments` table. And that's why the condition `if ($checkrows!=$ref) { ...` is failing.

You have to change your SQL query and the subsequent code in the following way,

```
// your code
$table_payments = $wpdb->prefix . "payments";
$check=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_payments WHERE Ref = '$ref'");
$checkrows=$wpdb->num_rows;

if ($checkrows == 0) {
    // do INSERT operation
}
```

Moreover, you should make `Ref` column of your table *unique*

Comment: hi it is still inserting records with same ref no

Comment: Hi i made the Ref column type unique and its working with this.But isn't it possible through code

Comment: @Mithu Ah, I made a mistake there. `$check->num_rows;` should be `$wpdb->num_rows`. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: r u talking about this $checkrows=$wpdb->num_rows;

Comment: @Mithu Yes, this one. Previously it was `$checkrows=$check->num_rows;`, which is incorrect. So I changed it to `$checkrows=$wpdb->num_rows;`.